# Wordpress error after upgrade "cannot redeclare" + "eval()'d"

Tags: wordpress, eval

Getting this error after a forced wordpress upload (I was working in the database when at one point of time I got an alert - while on the backend, with only one option to upgrade to the newer available version):

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _421736532() (previously declared in /home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyelevenmodified/header.php(68) : eval()'d code:1) in /home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyelevenmodified/header.php(68) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

The above is when I try mydomain.com

When I try mydomain.com/wp-admin/, I am redirected to wp-login.php and getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _421736532() (previously declared in /home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-login.php(80) : eval()'d code:1) in /home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-login.php(80) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Pulling my hair out trying different things since 5 hours now. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: After testing, I found that the function.php file is correctly calling function twentyeleven_header_style() and the problem is coming just after calling this function. So it's the next function call that is causing the problem. If I could know what is the next function !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I found that the site in question was hacked. More than 100 files were corrupted with codes. I cleaned them all and now things are functioning.

For others facing the same problem, download the whole files to your computer and look for eval codes (can be easily recognized).

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't use functions with those names. Deactivate your plugins or rename the plugins folder.

If that doesn't work then it's probably coming from your theme. Rename your theme folder so wordpress will revert to the default (assuming the default theme exists).

It sounds like you purchased a theme or plugin with obfuscated code and it's using `eval()` to run it and probably making a call home.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I renamed plugin to plugin-old, but that changed nothing. Anything else ?

Comment: Rob I tried changing theme name as well. I'm using the twentyelevenmodified theme. It probably has come after I got an alert for a database upgrade, though I cannot remember well.